# Setting up websockets, sticky sessions, and SSL all together on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: ssl, amazon-web-services, websocket, socket.io, amazon-elb

We're currently trying to get the following things working together:

- Websockets
- Sticky sessions
- SSL
- Elastic Beanstalk

We have attempted to switch our ELB incoming port configuration from HTTP/HTTPS to TCP/SSL which was successful in getting websockets to work.

However, our system depends on sticky sessions and it is impossible to get sticky sessions through TCP/SSL. We'd like to find a method where we can have both websockets and sticky sessions on SSL.

We did see this blog that proposes a workaround, but it looks like the workaround gets rid of Elastic Beanstalk, which we would still love to use. (http://johan.heapsource.com/post/31047804966/the-state-of-websockets-ssl-and-sticky-sessions).

Would really appreciate any help or advice from the community!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it looks like there is a lack of interest in this.  After much research, it still appears AWS ELB can't do sticky+websockets.

The only actual solution is to not use ELB and use nginx or something else and manage this yourself. So more work to do it seems.

Comment: As much as I didn't want to believe this answer, after doing a ton of my own research on this, I have to agree. sticky+websockets is just not possible at the moment.